# Pandas Time-Series Conditional Logic with Shift

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, conditional-statements

I would like a deeper explanation of what it going on with this code below:

`off_indices = s.loc[(s>0) & (s.shift(-1) == 0)].index`

It appears that `s.shift(-1) == 0` is resolving `s == 0` first and then `.shift(-1)` in the time series. Here is why that appears to be the case:

`off_indices`

`Int64Index([486, 1909, 3010, 3743, 3778], dtype='int64')`

But the s is actually zero at index 487, not 486.

`test['ENGINE_SPEED_VAL'][485:488]`

`485    2395.0`

`486    2396.0`

`487       0.0`

Why does it appear that s == 0 is resolving before s.shift(-1) is executed?

Comment: It seems like it works as you expect it to work (i.e. s.shift(-1) is evaluated and then == 0 is evaluated): (487,0.0) gets shifted to 486, which is why it evaluates True in == 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't shift(-1) go from decreasing order of the index and not increasing (i.e. 487-486, not 486-487)? I guess I'm misunderstanding the difference between shift(-1) and shift(1). Because in this example going from index 486-487 is a time step from 4:00 PM to 4:01 PM. I would have thought that would be shift(1) not shift(-1).

Comment: I'd advise to check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) but my understanding is since you didn't specify freq, it's literaly just shifting index (since it's -1, values from 487 goes into 486)

Comment: What I'm trying to do, which this code does correctly is find every time interval where the engine was on (engine speed > 0) and followed by the engine being off (an engine speed of 0). If .shift(-1) isn't there I can't find those values, but I don't understand why the -1 is necessary. It seems like shift(1) would be necessary. I know I didn't specify a frequency and I understand why 486 is returned in that context. I just don't understand how s.shift(-1) == 0 works in this example. Its seems like the logic is saying s>0 (index 486) and then the next index (487) equals 0 (s.shift(-1) == 0)